# Using defined function instead of anonymous function as callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Why isn't it possible to use a defined function as event callback?

```
<div id="me">
  <input>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // $("#me").on('keyup', 'input', doit()); # doesn't work
  // $("#me").on('keyup', 'input', 'doit'); # neither does this
  $("#me").on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    doit();
  }); // well, this one works of course
});

function doit() {
  console.log($("input").val());
}
```

Comment: When you pass in doit() as the callback, you

Comment: you... its like you enter the void ;)

Comment: that comment is very suspenseful.

Comment: @Marc you guys are responsible for spitting my drink on my keyboard :)))))) still laughing ...

Comment: @NULL Read rest of his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18538182/297641) to fill the void :)

Comment: I'm a fan of cliffhangers \o/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the function in as a parameter.

```
$("#me").on('keyup', 'input', doit);
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it and this does work: http://jsbin.com/IZecIj/1/edit  But, I am still puzzled why this is the case. By the way, I had a typo in posted code, I had also tried `'doit'`.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour Same works with an alert so try using alert instead of `console.log`.. may be jsbin overrides `console.log`? not sure

Comment: @Vega, `console.log` works fine; I had used `'doit'` instead of `doit`.

Answer (score 6):

You should pass the function, not call it

```
$("#me").on('keyup', 'input', doit)
```

To clear why that is wrong, see this example:

```
$("#me").on('keyup', 'input', (function() {
  doit();
})());
```

Here you are passing an anonymous function and invoking it immediately, which is not what the event handler expects.

The problem is not in the difference between anonymous or not, the problem is that you are invoking the function instead of passing it.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass in `doit()` (**with** the "`()`")  as the callback, you're actually running the function at that point and passing in the *return value* of the function (likely `undefined`) as the callback. If you pass in just a reference to the named function `doit` then the function will be executed as the callback.

Comment: Welcome to SO Rob! ;-)

Comment: YES. Although I've been around a little bit. This is one of the first non-ant question I've answered though.

Answer (score 1):

when you say something=function(){ blah } in js, it stores that as text and parses it on the fly - so yes, you can.
For example:

```
CallMe = function(){ alert("blah!"); }
bobsCallback.setFunction( CallMe );
```

CallMe is like any other variable, but it's contents is the js for the function.
You can pass it around as a callback, or invoke like so:

```
alert("calling CallMe...");
CallMe();
```