# how to use a defined event handler function instead of anonymous function in plugins (slick slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

**I know how to use a event handler functions for [click, scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538106/using-defined-function-instead-of-anonymous-function-as-callback) and other default events.** Currently I am using a slider plugin called [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and its working fine, I want to replace my event handlers with defined functions instead of anonymous function.

```
$(slick).on('afterChange', function(slick, currentSlide) {
    //doing some thing
}
```

I want it to be

```
$(slick).on('afterChange', {slick, currentSlide}, myFunctionName);
```

But it is showing error, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the function reference

```
$(slick).on('afterChange', myFunctionName);
```

and accept parameters in the function i.e.

```
function myFunctionName(slick, currentSlide){}
```

Comment: Nice it works, Thanks. But as per the docs in the event handler functions the arguements should be second right? Can you please say why that is not working here (curious :))

Comment: @Abel, Those are not function argument, they will be available  as `event.data`

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more with an example (jsfiddle), it will be more helpful than the question.